# Issue With Showing Distinct fields using Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, distinct

```
        var getAllProducts = _productService.GetAllProducts();      
        if (productstest.Count > 0)
        {
            model.idproduct.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = "0",
                Text = _localizationService.GetResource("Common.All")
            });
            foreach (var m in getAllProducts)
                model.idproduct.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = m.Id.ToString(),
                    **Text = m.Size.Distinct().ToString(),**
                    Selected = model.Pid == m.Id

                });
        }

   public virtual IList<Product> GetAllProducts(bool showHidden = false)
    {
        var query = from p in _productRepository.Table
                    orderby p.Name
                    where (showHidden || p.Published) &&
                    !p.Deleted
                    select p;
        var products = query.ToList();
        return products;
    }
```

The issue is even i tried to populate the select list with distinct size using: Text = m.Size.Distinct().ToString(), but it shows the duplicate for instance 100 products are of size 33 cm , the list will populate the dropdownlist in the view with 33cm occuring 100 times , I dont want to show 100 times , just want to show 1 time, Can any one assist me with this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are only trying to show one product of each different size... if so initialising your getAllProducts variable like so will do the trick:

```
var getAllProducts = _productService.GetAllProducts().GroupBy(p => p.Size).Select(g => g.First());
```